# Execute GROUP BY HAVING in django orm on a many to many relationship?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following models:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, default="")


class Problem(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="problems")
    index = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
```

I want to execute the following query:

```sql
SELECT
    "p"."index",
    "p"."name",
    "p"."rating"
FROM
    problem p
WHERE
    p.id IN (
        SELECT
            pt.problem_id
        FROM
            problem_tags pt
            JOIN tag t ON pt.tag_id = t.id
        WHERE
            t.name IN ('math', 'binary search', 'implementation')
        GROUP BY
            pt.problem_id
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) = 3
    )
ORDER BY
    rating,
    index;
```

I used something like:

```py
Problem.tags.through.objects.values("problem_id").filter(
    tag__name__in=("math", "binary search", "implementation")
).annotate(count=models.Count("*")).filter(count=3)
```

But it issues the following query which the first `COUNT(*)` in `SELECT` is redundant and wrong:

```sql
SELECT
    "api_problem_tags"."problem_id",
    COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM
    "api_problem_tags"
    INNER JOIN "api_tag" ON ("api_problem_tags"."tag_id" = "api_tag"."id")
WHERE
    "api_tag"."name" IN ('math', 'binary search', 'implementation')
GROUP BY
    "api_problem_tags"."problem_id"
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 3
```

How can I get rid of the first `COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can you use `Count` and the `filter` parameter.

```
Problem.objects.annotate(
   tag_count=Count(
       'tags',
       filter=Q(tags__name__in=["math", "binary search", "implementation"],
   )
).filter(tag_count=3)
```

Comment: It does not produce the desired query, I suspect it's right for the use case but almost takes 3 times to execute compared to provided query in question.